# Access data in matplotlib histogram axes

Tags: python, unit-testing, matplotlib

Where is the data plotted stored in a matplotlib ax object drawing a histogram?

My scenario:
I've written a function which draws a custom histogram using matplotlib. I am writing a unit test and would like to test whether the plotted data

Ideal behaviour:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(some_data)
data_i_want = ax.plotted_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but the plt.hist(...) function returns the data for the histogram:

```
histinfo = plt.hist(data)
histinfo[0] #This is the information about the # of instances
histinfo[1] #This is the information about the position of the bins
```

If you want to get the information from the plot itself at all cost (assuming you have a barplot):

```
container = ax.containers[0] #https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/container_api.html
for rect in container: #https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle
    print(rect.xy)
```

You can get the containers, and those containers will contain the information about the plotted bars (rectangles) at the commented URL, you can find every information about that.

Ps.: You probably have to adapt the code for the specific instance, but this is a way to get some information from the plot. (It is possible that there is a better way to do it, this is the best i know)